# in iOS 8, How to request App Extension for editing image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

Lets say i have created an extension for editing image which is introduced in iOS8, i have implemented all `PHContentEditingController` methods:

```
 - (BOOL)canHandleAdjustmentData:(PHAdjustmentData *)adjustmentData;

 - (void)startContentEditingWithInput:(PHContentEditingInput *)contentEditingInput placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage;

 - (void)finishContentEditingWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(PHContentEditingOutput *))completionHandler;
```

but, how can we request for editing an UIimage from HostViewController.Please suggest

Comment: Not sure it's very clear what you are asking. Please can you provide more detail.

Comment: [Please Check this out Apple's Tutorial Dude](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/SamplePhotoEditingExtension/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014576-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

Answer (score 0):

This is from Apple:

```
- (void)startContentEditingWithInput:(PHContentEditingInput *)input
                placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
{
  UIImage *image = input.displaySizeImage;
  ....
}
```

You get the image here.